# Проверка наличия объекта полномочий у пользователя Web Dynpro

Tags: sap, abap

Есть несколько экранов в Web Dynpro, на которых определённые поля и кнопки должны быть активными или неактивными в зависимости от наличия объекта полномочий у пользователя. Пока в технологии Web Dynpro знаю немного, изучал документацию и искал всё что есть в интернете, но не понимаю с чего лучше начать и где именно реализовывать проверку AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT.